# Empty csv file downloading in jersey rest api

Tags: java, jersey, opencsv

I am trying to download the CSV file using rest api. I am using opencsv library to convert Bean to csv.

I have done debugging all the inputs like inputData and fileName are coming proper and [StatefulBeanToCsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/StatefulBeanToCsv.html) is writing to outputstream still empty file is downloading. Please find the code below

Resource method

```java
@GET
@Path("/{category}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadAdminFile(@PathParam("category") String adminFileCategory,@QueryParam ("subCategory") String subCategory) {
        AdminFileStreamingOutput streamingOutput = adminFileDataService.downloadAdminFile(adminFileCategory,subCategory);
        return Response.ok(streamingOutput).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + streamingOutput.getFileName() + ";" + "charset=UTF-8")
                .build();
}
```

AdminFileStreamingOutput.java

```java
public class AdminFileStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    private Collection<?extends Serializable> inputData;

    private String fileName;

    public AdminFileStreamingOutput(Collection<?extends Serializable> inputData,String fileName) {
        this.inputData = inputData;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
        StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder
                .withSeparator(';')
                .build();
        try {
            beanWriter.write(this.inputData.iterator());
        } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException  e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to download admin file");
        }
    }
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

One of the Bean which is using OpenCSV annotations for mapping strategy

```java
public class ProjectInfo implements Serializable {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ProjectName",required = true)
    private String projectName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ProjectCode",required = true)
    private String projectCode;

   //setters and getters
}
```

Can anyone help me to find out the issue?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try flushing the output stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using flush it's downloading the file with content. Here is the changes

```java
@Override
    public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))){
            StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);
            StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder
                    .withSeparator(';').build();
            try {
                beanWriter.write(this.inputData.iterator());
                writer.flush();
            } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException  e) {
                throw new CMMV1Exception("Failed to download admin file");
            }
        }

    }
```

@ Paul Samsotha thanks a lot for your comment